# creating SQLITE query using boolean logic (AND, OR, NOT)

Tags: android, sqlite, boolean-logic

I'm using sqlite version 3.7 for my android application, I'm just not sure despite looking on the internet as well as this form, if it supports or if there is an alternative way to use boolean expressions in a query. I know we have to use 1/0 integers if we want to store boolean values into the database. but

for example: WHERE (a=1 || b=1) && c=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand.. Why not using classical SQL ?
WHERE (a = 1 OR b = 1) AND c = 1

Comment: Can you actually use sql with sqlite though ?

Comment: I read these forums that apparently you can't use full features of sql with sqLite, but I guess it could have been for full version ?

Comment: There can be some differences between every SQL engine. But the base remains the same. (arf, my poor english, hope you understand me). SQLite is not as powerfull that MS SQL server for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use AND, OR, etc. Find more at [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)